# What is the purpose of the magnet in our earpieces?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life

I understand that we have magnets embedded inside our earpieces and that causes then to repel when put together in close proximity.

For me, this raises two questions:  what is the purpose of these magnets? And wouldn’t these magnets affect our wellbeing?

Comment: I would like to ask as to why this question was downvoted and how I can improve it?

Comment: You could improve it by doing some research about earphones/loudspeakers. eg [Why do earphone pieces repel each other when music is on?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1326) Another reason for the downvote may be the naivety of the question : it is common knowledge that all goods these days have safety standards, and if it was known that they were bad for your health they would either be banned or would carry a government health warning and be heavily taxed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnets are part of the miniature loudspeakers inside the buds that turn electrical signals into sound.

There is no evidence to suggest that the magnets in your earbuds affect your health.